# Arch Linux not connecting to Wifi anymore

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi

I have been using Arch Linux over a month now. I have used `wifi-menu` to connect to my Wifi Network. I run the command every time I start my laptop.

`wifi-menu` always gives this error when I try to connect:

```
Job for netctl@HelloWorld.service failed. See 'systemctl status netctl@HelloWorld.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

The problem was that my interface was up every time I started. So I put the interface down using this:

```
ip link set down wlp2s0
```

`wlp2s0` is my interface's name and `HelloWorld` is my Wifi Network's SSID.

---

This time, it didn't connect to the network regardless of putting the interface down. It gives me the same error described above.

This is the output of `systemctl status netctl@HelloWorld.service`:

```
netctl@HelloWorld.service - Networking for netctl profile HelloWorld
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl@.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2014-03-24 02:32:35 IST; 2min 56s ago
     Docs: man:netctl.profile(5)
  Process: 8601 ExecStart=/usr/lib/network/network start %I (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Main PID: 8601 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 24 02:32:34 lenovo network[8601]: Starting network profile 'HelloWorld'...
Mar 24 02:32:35 lenovo network[8601]: chmod: cannot access ‘/run/dhcpcd-wlp2s0.pid’: No such file or directory
Mar 24 02:32:35 lenovo network[8601]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'HelloWorld'
Mar 24 02:32:35 lenovo systemd[1]: netctl@HelloWorld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 24 02:32:35 lenovo systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile HelloWorld.
Mar 24 02:32:35 lenovo systemd[1]: Unit netctl@HelloWorld.service entered failed state.
```

---

`journalctl -xn` gives me this output:

```
Mar 24 02:38:05 lenovo kernel: brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
Mar 24 02:38:05 lenovo kernel: cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Mar 24 02:38:05 lenovo dhcpcd[256]: wlp2s0: carrier lost
Mar 24 02:38:05 lenovo dhcpcd[256]: wlp2s0: carrier acquired
Mar 24 02:38:05 lenovo dhcpcd[256]: wlp2s0: carrier lost
Mar 24 02:38:05 lenovo dhcpcd[256]: wlp2s0: waiting for carrier
Mar 24 02:38:05 lenovo network[8993]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'HelloWorld'
Mar 24 02:38:05 lenovo systemd[1]: netctl@HelloWorld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 24 02:38:05 lenovo systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile HelloWorld.
-- Subject: Unit netctl@HelloWorld.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit netctl@HelloWorld.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 24 02:38:05 lenovo systemd[1]: Unit netctl@HelloWorld.service entered failed state.
```

systemctl gives the error that `/run/dhcpcd-wlp2s0.pid` doesn't exist, and it doesn't. Though a file named `/run/dhcpcd.pid` does exist.

---

This is the Network Controller output from `lspci -k`

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 051b
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

---

I have tried a couple of things from around the Internet but haven't found a solution.

Is there a way to fix this problem? Or can I just reset everything related to networking in Arch Linux so that I can just use `wifi-menu` to connect to the network again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

I had exactly the same problem. Have you killed the `dhcpd`?

I completely killed dhcpd:

`$ sudo killall dhcpcd`

After I disabled my wireless interface (`$ ip link set down $` should work too):

`$ sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down`

and my wifi-menu is working again.

Comment: I ran the commands but now it's telling me that the interface is controlled by netctl-auto. I couldn't find a way to disable that in the wiki.

Comment: The Error is:
Interface 'wlp2s0' is controlled by netctl-auto
A profile already exists for SSID 'HelloWorld'

Comment: no need to call "up" again?

Comment: Lol.. Killing DHCPCD really nailed it. Thanks a bunch

Comment: yeeeaahhh, thanks for this. @Alex, no need to call up again.

Comment: Just to weigh in, I specifically had to *not* call up again. `ifconfig wlan0 down` first, then `wifi-menu` worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you running wifi-menu each time you start? Unless you are constantly connecting to new wireless networks, you should simply use wifi-menu once to create a profile, then use [netctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl) to automatically connect when you boot.

Comment: The changes I did because of this bug enabled the netctl-auto command to start wifi at boot. Now, it connects to the network at boot and I can use netctl-auto to reconnect. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Probably a very late answer, but you can restart the dhcpcd, with the device down. And it should work.

`$ ip link set dev wlp9s0b1 down`

`$ wifi-menu`

if wifi-menu does not work, try installing networkmanager. and enabling it.

`\# pacman -S networkmanager`

`\# systemctl enable NetworkManager.service`

and restart.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I used `netctl enable [PROFILE]` to enable my wifi profile.